# How to get messages unread of a active user in a web-app with google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have a problem with a webapp. 
I want to know the number of messages's user unread. 
When i get the active user, it's the good email but it's my number of messages unread. 
The script is a web app set to "execute as me" (the developer)

My function :

```
function getNumberUnreadMail(){  
  // Get Active user
  var email= Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // Get "Unread" Labels Informations
  var response = Gmail.Users.Labels.get(email,'UNREAD');
  // TODO : manage value of response & errors
  if(response){
    var unreadNumber = response.messagesUnread;
    // return Total Number of Messages Unread
    return unreadNumber;
  } else {
    Logger.log('Error');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you not set "Execute the app as: User accessing the web app"?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()` this returns number of unread emails in Inbox.

Comment: Thanks ..
I have used this before but they take the messages of Effective User and not Active User. I dont want that the user has permissions on the script. (Launching the script)

Comment: However if I choose : Execute the app as user accessing the web app and i'm setting the script to read only, i think it works